# Local copy of word document loaded from shared drive not working with VBA saveas PDF method. Doesn't save the document

Tags: vba, ms-word, shared, drive

I have a macro that works fine in the shared drive when it is only accessed by one/first person. When it is accessed by the second person while the first person still has it open, it says it's already open. When I click "create a local copy and merge changes later" the macro will work up until it saves the file.

The macro basically invokes a userform to collect information, fill in the document, and then it should save the document as a PDF to the desktop. The PDF isn't saving in the local copy version for some reason. When the "Follow hyperlink" comes up, it says "Error 4198, command failed". I check my desktop and the file isn't there, leading me to believe that this error is in relation to the file not being created....

I just need the macro to allow the document to be saved to their desktop as a pdf, whether they're in the normal version, or the local copy created as a byproduct of the shared drive rules.

```
Main_Form.hide
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
sName = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & " Denial Letter - Invoice " & Invoice_Text.Value & ".pdf"
sPath = enviro & "\Desktop\"
ThisDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=sPath & sName, fileformat:=wdFormatPDF
fullName = sPath & sName

ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink fullName
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template (dotm), not a document. Create new documents from the template, that way there will be no document "lock".

Also, don't use `ThisDocument`as that means specifically the document in which the VBA code is located, use `ActiveDocument`, instead.

Comment: When I do that and they open up the dotm, the code I have in the document open event doesn't work, subsequently, the userform isn't called. This did fix the multiple hands in the cookie jar problem though. - Well, it's selectively calling. Weird. Sometimes it'll pop up the enable macros banner and when enabled, call it, but now it isn't. Very sporadic.

Comment: @BrandonLewallen No one should *open* the dotm, they should be creating new documents from it. Any code you have that should run at that time needs to be in the "New" event (or AutoNew macro). Double-clicking on a dotm or selecting it in File/New will create a new document.

Comment: @BrandonLewallen Has your original question now been answered?

Comment: Partially it has, it allows them all to access it, but for whatever reason, when the file is then saved as a pdf, and subsequently closed, the vba project stays "active" so when they go to open/create new document again from the template, it has the old information stored in the userform or it won't execute the "on document open event"

Comment: The original question is about allowing multiple users to be able to save these documents. If that is answered, then it's time to mark this question as such and open a new one with the altered background information and code. From the current perspective there's not enough information to deal with the problems cropping up from the changes that have been made when moving to a template environment. We'd need to see all the code involved.

Comment: Also, make sure the documents (not the pdf) are actually being closed - probably without changes if you're only interested in the PDFs? And, again, when creating a new document an OPEN event will NOT fire. A NEW event is required.

Comment: I've updated it to show that your response was the answer. I believe the New event helped fix the other issue I was experiencing. I appreciate your help.